# Rails: class' object_id changes after I make a request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I really can't explain this behavior, notice how after I make a request the class' object id has changed, and therefore my is_a? evaluation returns false.

any ideas? I'm not even sure how to debug this. Also, this isn't related to making a request from the command line. The same behavior is exhibited on the web server as well, it's just easier to explain from the command line.

```
staging$ RAILS_ENV=staging script/console
Loading staging environment (Rails 2.3.2)
>> c = CartItem.new
=> #<CartItem id: nil, order_id: nil, order_source: nil, date: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, paid: nil, payment_id: nil, values: nil, cart_description: nil, type: nil, price: nil, email: nil, error: nil>
>> c.class.object_id
=> 70151495336400
>> CartItem.object_id
=> 70151495336400
>> c.is_a? CartItem
=> true
>> app = ActionController::Integration::Session.new
=> #<ActionController::Integration::Session:0x7f9ad5c55db0 .... >
>> app.get("site/favorite")
=> 200
>> c.class.object_id
=> 70151495336400
>> CartItem.object_id
=> 70151496019760
>> c.is_a? CartItem
=> false
>> c.class
=> CartItem(id: integer, order_id: string, order_source: string, date: date, user_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, paid: boolean, payment_id: integer, values: text, cart_description: string, type: string, price: integer, email: string, error: string)
```

Comment: It shouldn't. There seems to be some sort of 'reload!' going on. Hard to tell without the full source code...

Comment: My guess is you are serializing the cart object fully into the session, and then restoring it.  This can be a tricky thing.

Comment: Hm, any suggestions on where or what to look for if this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

Every new context (request/response cycle) will regenerate the object IDs. You may want to use `responds_to?`, instead of `is_a?`.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. I guess the problem is slightly more complicated than I let on. CartItem is actually the base class for STI, so when I have a subclass A < CartItem, and a = A.new. Not only will a.is_a? CartItem fail (which you provided a work around for), but 'a' ceases to inherit the methods of CartItem, which kind of defeats the purpose of STI...

Answer (score 1):

Since the `ActionController::Integration` module is used for integration testing, `get`ting a url reloads your classes, therefore redefining the `CartItem` identifier. You now basically have **two** CartItem classes, one hanging around on your stack without an identifier pointing to it anymore (the "old one") and one referenced by the `CartItem` identifier.